# How to Add Resource with form-data Parameters in WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I Have a REST API Which Takes two Parameters Like the Image Below:

[image]

And as You See This is form-data Parameters.

How can I Add This to API Manager?

Comment: Which version of API Manager are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API Manager, from a UI perspective, we can only configure whether that particular API Resource requires a Body or Header. But, we can make use of the Swagger Editor to specify other fields.

I believe that your requirement is to show the mentioned two parameters as `multipart/form-data` properties in the Swagger UI. If so, make the following changes to the Swagger definition to display them (in Devportal). Assuming that you are using API Manager 3.x series, I have provided the Swagger snippet related to the OpenAPI definition

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
...
paths:
  /*:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                param1:
                  type: string
                param2:
                  type: object
                  format: binary
      ...
```

Hope this helps you to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Thanks For the Answer. I changed the Definition and it Worked. For the Param2 Which Takes the Image, I think I have to Call this Resource with Postman. Thank You Again :)

Comment: One more Question: How you wrote the Definition Above? Is there Any Editor or Something? I mean another editor except the Editor in Publisher.

Comment: Great!! No, I used the same Publisher Swagger Editor to perform the above-mentioned changes. You can learn more about the OpenAPI support with `multipart/form-data` [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/)